# How to run program after compiling with Makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I have a `assign4a.cpp`, `list.h`, and `list.cpp` file. I compiled them with my make file but don't know what command I would use to run the program.

**What I tried to run have tried**

`a.out`  and `./a.out`

both of them give me "Command not found"

**Makefile**

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -g
LFLAGS = -g -o assign4a

assign4a: assign4a.o list.o
    g++ assign4a.o list.o $(LFLAGS)

assign4a.o: assign4a.cpp list.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) assign4a.cpp

list.o: list.cpp list.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) list.cpp

clean:
    rm -f assign4a *.o *~ *#
```

Comment: In the future you should also try to run `ls` and see what your makefile produced as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./assign4a`.

Your makefile will build the program and put a executable `assign4a` to the working folder.

#### And, your makefile is wrong.

It should be `g++ $(CFLAGS) assign4a.cpp -o assign4a.o` and `g++ $(CFLAGS) list.cpp -o list.o`.

Comment: I am getting an ```error cannot execute binary file: Exec format error```. Please Help.

Comment: @MonuChaudhary i have no idea why you got that error. Are you running a cross-compiled binary?

Comment: @maowtw yes, it is a cross-compiled binary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
./assign4a
```

Makefile defines targets and dependencies between them. Here:

```
assign4a: assign4a.o list.o
    g++ assign4a.o list.o $(LFLAGS)
```

`assign4a` is a target, that depends on files `assign4a.o`, `list.o`, and to build target is needed to run `g++ assign4a.o list.o $(LFLAGS)`.